# Gridview paging display

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My gridview has 5 columns and the paging row automatically has a colspan = 5 added to that? Is there a way to remove the paging from the gridview table or place it a tfoot, or something like that so the paging layout isn't tied to what columns and cell data have? The numbers span the entire table...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove enable or disable the paging a few different ways. If your gridview is connected up to a datasource, you can click on the smart tag on the gridview when you are in Design view. If not, you can right click on the gridview, click on properties, then scroll down and you can see "Paging." It may already be expanded, if not expanded that and you can set "AllowPaging" to false. Here, you can also change the page size. By default, it's usually set to 10. In this properties, you can actually set the PagerSettings as well. You may have to click the plus sign to expand it. You can change the position to "Bottom", "Top", or even both with "TopAndBottom." If I understood you correctly, this should help you out!